# Playing Videos using MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uivideoeditorcontroller

Now I am here with new question related to `MPMoviePlayer`. I am having a table view that lists the videos on one side of ipad, on other side - I play the video selected in list. These happens in same view. Now switching to different videos works fine. Now when I am editing the video using `UIVideoEditorController`, I am replacing the current video file in documents folder and then play the video again. But then my player stops working...

I think the issue is that player within the `UIVideoEditorController` is not released properly. I released the editor but still I am there only.. NOTHING WORKS AGAIN :(

Please help me asap

```
-(void)playVideoWithIndex:(NSNumber *)index1
{
int index = [index1 intValue];
indexVideo = [index1 intValue];
if(index > [SourceArray count]){
    NSLog(@"dg");
    return;
}

if (mp) {
    [mp stop];
    [mp.view removeFromSuperview];
    [mp release];
    mp=nil;
}
//  NSArray *sourcePaths=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"mov" inDirectory:nil]];
videoDtls *v =[SourceArray objectAtIndex:index];
lbl_date.text=v.iVideoDate;
lbl_Title.text=v.iVideoTitle;
lbl_description.text=v.iVideoDesc;
lblDesc.text = @"Description";

lable_title.text = v.iVideoTitle;
NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *mainImageFolderPath=[documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"];
NSString *urlStr  = [mainImageFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:v.iVideoPath];
self.vpath = urlStr;
NSLog(@"asdsd %@",urlStr);
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];


mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
{
    // Set movie player layout
    //[mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];

    //[mp setFullscreen:YES];
    // May help to reduce latency
    [mp prepareToPlay];
    mp.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
//  mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
//  mp.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
    // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerEnterFullScreen:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerExitFullScreen:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:) 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
     object:nil];

    [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    // Add movie player as subview
    [playerView addSubview:[mp view]];   
    mp.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;




}  
else
{
    // Register to receive a notification when the movie is in memory and ready to play.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

// Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

}

This method is called when a video is played from table view..

```
- (void)videoEditorController:(UIVideoEditorController *)editor didSaveEditedVideoToPath:(NSString *)editedVideoPath
{
CFShow(editedVideoPath);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *path = self.vpath;
NSLog(@"PATH %@", self.vpath);
if([fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error] != YES){
    NSLog(@"ERROR 1 : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
// can do save here. the data has *not* yet been saved to the photo album
if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:editedVideoPath toPath:path error:&error] != YES)
    NSLog(@"Can't move file with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
[popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
[editor release];
[self performSelector:@selector(playVideoWithIndex:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexVideo] afterDelay:0.2];
```

}

This method is called when editor returns successfully. 
After This my video does not play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved issue by using UIVideoEditorController in another view controller and then delaying playing video for fraction of second. May this happened because I was trying to play a video that was being replaced.